# "Be accustomed to" Vs "Get used to"

Tags: verbs, idioms

I need to discover the semantic nuance between the phrasal verb "be accustomed to" and the idiom "get used to"!

E.g. please let me know how do the following examples differ in meaning:

> - We've **been accustomed** to working together.
> - We've **got used  to** working together.

Or

> - It takes you a long time to **get used to it**.
> - It takes you a long time to **be accustomed to it**.

Or

> - He **got used to** finding fault with everything.
> - He is **accustomed to** finding fault with everything.

Or

> - I've **got used to** drinking my liquor neat.
> - I'm **accustomed to** drinking my liquor neat.

For me, all for pairs mean the same and the only difference is that "be accustomed to sth" is a formal term in English! Although, I have my doubts yet!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are *different* differences within the examples as presented (which I'm sure aren't exhaustive regarding *possible* distinctions, but let's stay focused).

> 1a: *We've been accustomed to working together.*
>    1b: *We've got used to working together.*
>    1c: *We are accustomed to working together.*

I've included a third alternative because that's a more common version that most closely matches **1a** in implication *(working together is what we're used to / **expect**)*. **1b** could imply we might not even have *wanted* to work together when we started *(but now we've come to **tolerate, bear, put up with*** the situation.

---

> 2a: *It takes you a long time to get used to it.*
>    2b: *It takes you a long time to be accustomed to it.*
>    2c: *It takes you a long time to become accustomed to it.*

Where **2c** replaces non-idiomatic **2b**. I can't really see any scope for saying either version could imply anything different to the other. I'm sure **2a** would be far more common in relaxed speech, but there's wrong with the slightly more formal **2c**.

---

> 3a: *He got used to finding fault with everything.*
>    3b: *He is accustomed to finding fault with everything.*

Where **3a** implies that he didn't *want* to keep finding fault(s), but they were there and he couldn't avoid them (perhaps he worked as a Quality Inspector). After a some time, it no longer bothered him that he had to keep finding fault(s).

**3b**, on the other hand strongly implies that he *does* want to find fault. Similar to **1a** above, in that the implication is he both ***wants*** and ***expects*** to do so.

---

> 4a: *I've got used to drinking my liquor neat.*
>    4b: *I'm accustomed to drinking my liquor neat.*

Unquestionably here, **4a** implies that originally you didn't like drinking neat liquor, but you had to do it so often you can now at least *tolerate* (and even perhaps *enjoy*) it. Whereas **4b** might be a somewhat "imperious" request / command *(Give me a glass of neat liquor, because that's what you normally have, and it's what you're expecting now).* Or a withering complaint, if you've just been handed a glass of watered-down whisky when you wanted it full strength.

---

The main difference (apart from the fact that ***used to*** is much more common than ***accustomed to***), is that *usually*, to ***be / get used to*** is more closely associated with ***adapting*** to a situation (through past exposure), whereas to be ***accustomed to*** often implies ***expecting / wanting*** some past pattern to be repeated in a current or future situation.

Comment: thank you for the comprehensive response, but I think it would be more helpful if you could rephrase or somehow edit this post in the manner that I could grasp your meaning! It seems me a little ambiguous! I guess perhaps you have changed it several times!

Comment: I don't know where to start. Well, I *did* know - I started my answer here by pointing out that there are *different* differences, at the levels of meaning, syntax, prevalence, and register / formality. So far as I can see, I've given a brief outline of (possible) differences for each of the 4 groups of alternative contexts in your question. You're *not* going to get an answer along the lines of ***Used to** always means X, and **accustomed to** always means Y*, because there isn't one. But if there's *one example* above that you don't understand, just tell me and I'll try to explain further.

Comment: thank you for your concern and your attention! But the differences in meaning of my for provided examples are not understandable for me at all! I would be really appreciative if you do me a favor and somehow make your answer easier to be grasped! Thank you in advance. :)

Comment: That's not a meaningful response. Let's focus on just your *first* example. I assume you understand what I mean when I say that your **1a** is relatively uncommon, and my **1c** is the "more likely" equivalent. Apart from that, I've pointed out that **1a / 1c** primarily allude to what we ***expect / desire***. Whereas **1b** is about what we've come to ***tolerate*** (due to repeated past exposure),with the implication that we don't (or at least *didn't*) particularly want it. Do you not understand that?

Comment: Let me summarize my take on your response! **1.** You mean that "to be accustomed to something" is an interchangeable equivalent for "to get used to something" while "to become accustomed to something" is not; because its structure is uncommon! **2.** You want to say that: "be accustomed to sth" is more about what you **expect** or what you **desire** while the structure "get used to sth" is mostly used to indicate that you used to **tolerate sth** or even you are tolerating now! Do you confirm it?

Comment: do you confirm it?

Comment: Yes. It's not a 100% *fixed* distinction, but that ***accustomed to = expect, used to = tolerate*** very often applies. But there are further subtleties depending on the exact *form* of the verb. For example ***I am accustomed to a cooked breakfast every day*** could be used if the speaker has *always* had a cooked breakfast throughout his life (so naturally he wants and expects one *today*). But ***I have become accustomed to a cooked breakfast every day*** very strongly (unambiguously, I'd say) implies that there *was* a time (perhaps long ago) when I only used to get a bowl of cereal.

Comment: ...and don't get me started on the difference between *I only **used to** get cereal* and *I was **used to** only getting cereal*. If you don't understand that one, you'll have to ask another question here on ELL! :)

Comment: Many thanks to you for you ever-informative posts on my questions. :)