# "Accustom someone to sth" Vs "make someone get used to sth"

Tags: verbs

In order to discover the semantic difference between these two words, I need to figure out how the following sentences differ in meaning:

> - Try to **make your child get used to** healthy foods.
> - Try to **accustom your child to** healthy foods.

Comment: It's *something*, not *sth*.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Be accustomed to" Vs "Get used to"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/205438/be-accustomed-to-vs-get-used-to)

Comment: @Jason Bassford thank you for the attention; I am trying to give up this habit of mine and write completely! Meanwhile, the previous question did not solve my problem completely and whereas I have flagged several threads to the moderators and they were left unresponded, so I decided raising a separated case grasp find out the semantic neance beweet the two structures! Hopefuly, "virolono" solved the problem here!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"make" somebody do something implies "forcing" somebody to do something.

The two sentences would have the same meaning if you would change "make" with "help":

> Try to **help** your child **get used to** healthy foods.

Comment: Thank you @virolino , but to make it clearer let's suppose two other examples; in a case of difficulty which someone is going through, how do the following sentences differ in meaning: **Try to make yourself get used to these conditions** VS **Try to accustom yourself to these conditions**? The same goes here?

Comment: **"Try to get yourself used to these conditions"** and **"Try to accustom yourself to these conditions"** have the same meaning. No need for "make", which again implies "against your own wish".

Comment: Therefore, ommiting "make" in my original post and replacing it with the structure "get someone used to something" and just saying: **"Try to get your child used to healthy food"** would be an equivalent for "accustom your child". Right?

Comment: Yes, that is my understanding.